# python fedex api problems

Tags: python, api, fedex

I want to use FedEx API for shipping in python. 
I installed fedex lib:

```
pip install fedex
```

but when I try to use it I got an error. Help, please.

```
from fedex.config import FedexConfig

CONFIG_OBJ = FedexConfig(key='<key>',
password='<pass>',
account_number='<account_no>',
meter_number='<meter_no>')
```

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from fedex.config import FedexConfig
ImportError: No module named config
```

the install, and upgrade

```
root@server:~#  pip install fedex
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): fedex in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): suds-jurko in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from fedex)

root@server:~# pip install fedex --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: fedex in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: suds-jurko in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from fedex)
Cleaning up...
```

Comment: This is probably because you ran pip as root which it advises you not to do. Try removing that package and then doing `pip install fedex --user` as a normal user.

Comment: What happens when you do `import fedex` and `import fedex.config`. Also, what does running `python --version` in the shell output?

Comment: Kredns 1: I did but, not working yet. ........Mad Physicist : Python 2.7.6, also i got the same error just on the import line

Comment: Is your Python script called `fedex.py` by any chance?  If so, try changing its name to something else.

Comment: I found it!!, for some reason, I have fedex, pyfedex-1.2.egg-info, and pyfedex-1.2-py2.7.egg on the /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages folder. I just remove the last 2 and work well :)

Comment: My issue was that I had named the script fedex.py. No idea why that was causing an error. Thanks @LukeWoodward

Comment: @beetree if your script is named `fedex.py` then that means it defines a module named `fedex`.  So when you try to import something from `fedex` Python thinks you're trying to import from your module rather than the installed module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were you able to get this package to work? While i was able to define everything in the config_obj, i keep getting a "FedexTrackRequests is not defined " error when trying to track a package via code below (with a proper tracking number entered in).

```
track = FedexTrackRequest(CONFIG_OBJ)
tracking_num = '############3'
track.SelectionDetails.PackageIdentifier.Type = 'TRACKING_NUMBER_OR_DOORTAG'
track.SelectionDetails.PackageIdentifier.Value = tracking_num
track.send_request()
```

Comment: Make sure to update self.SelectionDetails.CarrierCode = 'FDXG' or to the carriercode of the tracking number and also do .strip(" ") on the tracking number value to remove any white space. This resolved similar issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the 'FedexTrackRequest' is not defined error, you need to import the missing class. Do this by inputting this code at the top of your file. This worked for me:

from fedex.services.track_service import FedexTrackRequest

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the TrackRequest from track_service

```
from fedex.services.track_service import FedexTrackRequest
```